# Grails create-app does not produce build.xml?

Tags: grails, ant, build.xml

It is [said here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/4.%20The%20Command%20Line.html#4.5%20Ant%20and%20Maven) that `grails create-app` should produce a `build.xml` for ant or maven. However it does not (at least in version 1.3.7). How can I build it with ant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to allow your project to be built with ant you must tell it to integrate with ant. Use the following grails command from your project directory to do so.

```
grails integrate-with --ant
```

Answer (score 1):

With net-beans ide you can run grails command throw the right click option of your project root folder, and select "run/debug grails command...". 
Choose "integrate-with" command and put "--ant" as an argument.